# Excluding some components from authentication with angular-oauth2-oidc

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, angular-oauth2-oidc

I use angular-oauth2-oidc for authentication.
I am searching for a way to exclude some components from authentication.

I have a component, which is only for internal use and do not need any authentication. I plan to secure it with canActivate route guard and there check, if the url contains an internal ip (not called via Hostname).

But for this, I need first excluding the component from authentication. Can please someone give me a hint, how I can do this? Thank you.

Comment: Not sure what "exclude component from auth" means? Sounds like something specific to your application, could you post some code to reproduce your situation?